# Symfony2-Rookie: Setting Path dynamically

Tags: internationalization, routes, symfony, twig

ok,i managed to put code for my testpage to switch languages in combination with JMSTranslationBundle like this in twig

```
<li>
<a href="{{ path("main", {"_locale": "en","name": name}) }}">
<img src="{{ asset('img/flags/gb.png') }}"></a></li>
<li>
<a href="{{ path("main", {"_locale": "de","name": name}) }}">
<img src="{{ asset('img/flags/de.png') }}"></a></li>
```

but this will be working for the `path ("main")`
how can i make it dynamically work for the page/route i am currently working on, including needed parameter (in this case `"name": name` ? so if i am currently on english page of "about us", i can automatically switch to german page of about us, including its parameters? is it possible? or do i have to hardcode each twig page/template with the paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This describes an extension exactly like you are looking for: http://blog.viison.com/post/15619033835/symfony2-twig-extension-switch-locale-current-route

The `ScopeWideningInjectionException` can be fixed by injecting the `@service_container` to retrieve the router and request instead of injecting them directly.

Answer (score 3):

Hardcoding is a bad idea and this is achievable but not out of the box as far as I know. What I did to provide an url with the same path and params but for a different locale was to create a custom twig extension to do it.

This extension provide a new twig function that will read the current route, the current parameters, eliminate private parameters and generate the same route but for another locale. Here the twig extension in question:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\WebsiteBundle\Twig\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class LocalizeRouteExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $request;
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->request = $container->get('request');
        $this->router = $container->get('router');
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'localize_route' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'executeLocalizeRoute', array()),
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'localize_route_extension';
    }

    /**
     * Execute the localize_route twig function. The function will return
     * a localized route of the current uri retrieved from the request object.
     *
     * The function will replace the current locale in the route with the
     * locale provided by the user via the twig function.
     *
     * Current uri: http://www.example.com/ru/current/path?with=query
     *
     * In Twig: {{ localize_route('en') }} => http://www.example.com/en/current/path?with=query
     *          {{ localize_route('fr') }} => http://www.example.com/fr/current/path?with=query
     *
     * @param mixed $parameters The parameters of the function
     * @param string $name The name of the templating to render if needed
     *
     * @return Output a string representation of the current localized route
     */
    public function executeLocalizeRoute($parameters = array(), $name = null)
    {
        $attributes = $this->request->attributes->all();
        $query = $this->request->query->all();
        $route = $attributes['_route'];

        # This will add query parameters to attributes and filter out attributes starting with _
        $attributes = array_merge($query, $this->filterPrivateKeys($attributes));

        $attributes['_locale'] = $parameters !== null ? $parameters : \Locale::getDefault();

        return $this->router->generate($route, $attributes);
    }

    /**
     * This function will filter private keys from the attributes array. A
     * private key is a key starting with an underscore (_). The filtered array is
     * then returned.
     *
     * @param array $attributes The original attributes to filter out
     * @return array The filtered array, the array withtout private keys
     */
    private function filterPrivateKeys($attributes)
    {
        $filteredAttributes = array();
        foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
            if (!empty($key) && $key[0] != '_') {
                $filteredAttributes[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $filteredAttributes;
    }
}
```

Now, you can enable this twig extension by loading this service definition either via your bundle or directly into the `config.yml` file located under `app/config`.

```
    services:
      acme.twig.extension:
        class: Acme\WebsiteBundle\Twig\Extension\LocalizeRouteExtension
        scope: request
        arguments:
          request: "@request"
          router: "@router"
        tags:
          -  { name: twig.extension }
```

And now you can do this in twig to propose a different version of the current loaded page:

```
<a id='englishLinkId' href="{{ localize_route('en') }}">
  English
</a>
<a id='frenchLinkId' href="{{ localize_route('fr') }}">
  Français
</a>
```

Hope this helps and that is what you are looking for.

Edit:

It seems that it is not possible to narrow the scope of a twig extension directly. To avoid this, inject instead the dependency container all along and then retrieve the required services. This should be reflected by changing constructor definition of the twig extension and the service definition for the extension. I edited my previous answer, check the new updated constructor definition and the new service definition.

Another possible solution would be to inject an helper service that is responsible of localizing the route. This helper service should be in the request scope. In fact, this is what I have in my code. I have a `RoutingHelper` service that is injected in my twig extension. Then, in the method `executeLocalizeRoute`, I use my helper to do the hard work.

Tell me if everything is working now.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: sweet...looks really neat, thanks man..will try it out, important for me if it recognizes paramters....maybe a simpler option would be that each user defines their locale under settings, and it is automatically set from there....but i need this at least for pages without login.

Comment: i have tried your solution. but i get: '  Scope Widening Injection detected: The definition "twig" references the service "tracker.twig.extension" which belongs to a narrower scope. Generally, it is
safer to either move "twig" to scope "request" or alternatively rely on the provider pattern by injecting the container itself, and requesting the service "tracker.twig.extension" each time it is needed. In rare, special cases however that might not be necessary, then you can set the reference to strict=false to get
rid of this error.'

Comment: thanks, still getting same issue : ScopeWideningInjectionException....must be an easier path, like get_current_route and get_current params_ or something....they locale_ are always constant anyway...i just need the route and params.

Comment: To get the route, do `$request->attributes->get('_route')`. This will give you the route name. To get the parameters, do `$request->attributes->all()` and filter every value starting with an underscore.